# Resume an Iterator

Tags: python, iterator

Is there a way to resume an iterator after a keyboard interrupt signal or other SIGINT signal in python?

Specifically for itertools iterator

`import itertools
for word in itertools.product("abcd",repeat=3):
      print(word)`

I want to resume printing from where it left off

Comment: your code will exhaust the iterator, so it's not clear this question..

Answer (score 0):

You can catch keyboard interrupts in a try/except block

```
import itertools
import time
for word in itertools.product("abcd",repeat=3):
  try:
    print(word)
    time.sleep(1)
  except:
    pass
```

Hitting Ctrl+C during executing does not stop the iteration

Comment: I am thinking along the line of stopping the python program and whenever i restart it..the iterator resumes from where it left off...possible?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit reading on generators and the 'yield' statement.i've realized that generators only output a value, discard it and output another value and so forth... I was trying to find a way to resume output for the following function after python quits

```
counter=0
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    global counter
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    #yield pools
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        counter=counter+1
        if counter>11:
            yield tuple(prod)

def product_function():
    for i in product('abc',repeat=3):
        print(i)
        print(counter)

product_function()
```

I finally decided to put in the a little variable called counter and once the counter is greater that the 11th word then all over values (words) are yielded and printed. I suppose i could write some codes to store the counter variable in a separate file whenever the program quits and whenever the program restarts it pulls the last counter variable from the file so that output resumes. hope this works..